# Mono-Issues consistantly

Tags: monodevelop

o.k after 1 month and 4 Different Ubuntu Versions 18.04 18.10 19.10 20.01 and 
even Linux Mint even with complete updates and package installs of gtk and glade and 
many updates and all the packages,  on each one of them i consistantly always
missing the following  atk-sharp, gdk-sharp,  glib-sharp,  gtk-sharp, after performing
sudo apt-get for all these packages it comes back with nothing, after hovering over 
the red X's i get assembly not found for dot net 4.5 ,  so how are you guys 
getting GUI interfaces, what are you doing Different,

Comment: Change the project target framework version to 4.6 or 4.7. That might resolve the errors. Before .NET 5 release (Nov 2020) there can be significant issues using Mono on Linux, as efforts are not adequately allocated for it.

Comment: @Codebase-Versioning This does not seem a programming question.